# position nested divs in a responsive way

Tags: html, css, ember.js, responsive-design

I have some nested divs that need to be positioned next to eachother in a responsive way. This is my html:

```
<div class="map-tool">
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="ember473" class="draggableDropzone1 ember-view draggableDropzone deactivated">
    <div class="map-view  kinetic-active" id="wrapper" style="cursor: move;">
      <div id="ember482" class="ember-view">
        <div class="" style="position:relative;">
          <img id="dragMap" class="" src="*********">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ember483" class="draggableDropzone1 ember-view draggableDropzone deactivated">
    <div id="g-map-object" class="map-view ">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ember484" class="draggableDropzone2 ember-view draggableDropzone deactivated">
    <div class="legend-view ">
      <div id="ember493" class="ember-view">
        <div class="border-below">
          <p>Selected map:</p>
          <select id="ember502" tabindex="0" class="ember-view x-select">
            <option id="ember512" value="[object Object]" class="ember-view x-option">Tomorrowland floorplan</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hotspots-view ">
        <p class="places-available ">Places available</p>
        <div class="categories-buttons ">
          <div id="ember525" class="ember-view">
            <button class="cat-button" data-ember-action="529">Amusement</button>
            <button class="cat-button" data-ember-action="532">Stages</button>
            <button class="cat-button" data-ember-action="533">Tastes of the World</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="hiddenHotspot "><i class="fa fa-map-marker "></i>
  </p>
</div>
```

Class 'legend-view' needs to be positioned all the way to the right, and has a fixed width of 200.
Class 'map-view' is positioned on the left of the legend-view and takes all the remaining width space.

At the moment I'm working with width 75% and width 25% but this is not optimal as I need the fixed width for the legend-view.

The view consists of ember-views as this is the framework I'm working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added some styling to the HTML. The .legend-view should retain 200px, and the .map-view will be responsive to the remaining space. That is listed in the style section of the HTML.

In order to float right, the order of the divs had to be switched in the body. The "map-view" was moved below the "legend-view", so float:right; will put the "legend-view to the right first, before "map-view".

**Edit: I added background color to illustrate the div positioning.

```
<style>
  .legend-view {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    postion: relative;
    background-color: red;
  }

  .map-view {
    float: right;
    postion: relative;
    background-color: blue;
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 200px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 200px);
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
  }

</style>
```

```
<div class="map-tool">



  <div id="ember484" class="draggableDropzone2 ember-view draggableDropzone deactivated">
    <div class="legend-view ">
      <div id="ember493" class="ember-view">
        <div class="border-below">
          <p>Selected map:</p>
          <select id="ember502" tabindex="0" class="ember-view x-select">
            <option id="ember512" value="[object Object]" class="ember-view x-option">Tomorrowland floorplan</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="hotspots-view ">
        <p class="places-available ">Places available</p>
        <div class="categories-buttons ">
          <div id="ember525" class="ember-view">
            <button class="cat-button" data-ember-action="529">Amusement</button>
            <button class="cat-button" data-ember-action="532">Stages</button>
            <button class="cat-button" data-ember-action="533">Tastes of the World</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="map"></div>

  <div id="ember473" class="draggableDropzone1 ember-view draggableDropzone deactivated">
    <div class="map-view  kinetic-active" id="wrapper" style="cursor: move;">
      <div id="ember482" class="ember-view">
        <div class="" style="position:relative;">
          <img id="dragMap" class="" src="*********">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ember483" class="draggableDropzone1 ember-view draggableDropzone deactivated">
    <div id="g-map-object" class="map-view ">
    </div>
  </div>

  <p class="hiddenHotspot "><i class="fa fa-map-marker "></i>
  </p>
</div>
```